# Counting datediff from 2 date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I have 2 datetime fields, `NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE` and `NEW_EMPLOYMENT_ENDDATE`

When I calculate the difference in months using `datediff` with these values for `startdate` and `enddate`:

```
NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE = 2017-15-01
NEW_EMPLOYMENT_ENDDATE = 2018-14-01
```

With this query:

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH, NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE, NEW_EMPLOYMENT_ENDDATE)
```

It returns 12 months, but when I have values like this:

```
NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE = 2017-01-01
NEW_EMPLOYMENT_ENDDATE = 2017-31-12
```

It returns 11 months.

How can I get 12 months? I am using this query:

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH, NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE, NEW_EMPLOYMENT_ENDDATE)-
CASE 
WHEN DATEPART(DAY, NEW_EMPLOYMENT_ENDDATE) > DATEPART(DAY, NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE) 
THEN 0
ELSE 0 END AS MONTH_DIFF
```

It still returns 11 months.

EDIT:

According to my case, the value of the end date always less 1 day from start date, so i make a trick to check condition with case when like this:

```
CASE
WHEN DATEPART(DAY, NEW_EMPLOYMENT_ENDDATE) > DATEPART(DAY, NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE)
THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE, NEW_EMPLOYMENT_ENDDATE)+1
ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH, NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE, NEW_EMPLOYMENT_ENDDATE)
END AS DATEDIF
```

i add + 1 value to the end date so i ta can be round to next month, give feedback from my solution sir thanks

Comment: Result of function is pretty correct, since from first day of year till the last day it will be only 11 **full** months. The same logic is here: `select datediff(mm, '20160101','20160131')` will return you 0 months, since it is not **full** month between these dates. So if you need to change this logic - you should not rely on `datediff` and instead  you have to write couple of conditions to check month and year of starting and ending date.

Comment: Between 1 and 12 there are only 11 months why you want 12 months as result ?

Comment: Your solution, this works for the data presented, but what if the employee doesn't have an end date that is the last day of the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expectations are incorrect. When you do a `DATEDIFF` using `MONTH`, it does not consider the day portion of the dates. Consider that it is simply considering the difference in the month numbers only, regardless of the day specified.

This query:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(MONTH, '20170101', '20171231') MonthsDiff
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, '20171231') - DATEPART(MONTH, '20170101') MonthsDiff
```

The documentation for <kbd>[DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)</kbd> states:

> DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )

The first option is `DATEPART`:

> *datepart*
>   Is the part of startdate and enddate that specifies the type of boundary crossed.

If you want something closer to what you expect, you can do a simple calculation based on performing the `DATEDIFF` in days, the dividing it by the approximate number of days in a month.

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(DAY, '20170101', '20171231') / ( 365 / 12 ) MonthsDiff
```

This will round the output to the closest month number, it all depends on how accurate you want to be. If you want months as a decimal for greater accuracy then run the below:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(DAY, '20170101', '20171220') / ( 365.00 / 12 ) MonthsDiff
```

**Note:** This does not take into account leap years, for larger date ranges that might include leap years, which will make a minor difference to the accuracy.

Comment: Your query incorrect.  Year does not have 365 days.
And, if looking forward, you dont know how mutch days month have.

Comment: @Juozas care to explain why a year, or the given year (2017), doesn't have 365 days????

Comment: Hardcode - bad practice. We can't talk about the year value at all. We can talk about the year X with days Y. Code, that works only in special conditions, really does not works.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this is just an example, I'm not claiming it to be bullet proof code. The OP hasn't stated how accurate he wants the output to be, so all i can do is make suggestions. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

`datediff()` does something very particular.  It counts the number of "boundaries" between two date/time values.  In your case, there are eleven boundaries -- one for each month in the year before December.

This behavior is not necessarily intuitive.  If you add one day to each of your dates:

```
NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE = '2017-01-02'  (YYYY-MM-DD is standard format)
NEW_EMPLOYMENT_ENDDATE = '2018-01-01'
```

Then you will have 12 months.

If you want to round up, you can play with the dates.  One method would be to normalize the first value to the beginning of the month and then add 15 days to the second value:

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH,
         DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE), NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE)
         DATEADD(DAY, 15 + 1 - DAY(NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE), NEW_EMPLOYMENT_ENDDATE)
        )
```

This would happen to work for the two examples you give.

Comment: End date needs to be: `2018-01-01` doesn't it?

Comment: Your code has bugs and does not works with values: 
NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE 2017-01-01   
NEW_EMPLOYMENT_ENDDATE 2017-03-30

Answer (score 0):

Please use this select to achieve your desired result. You can use table columns instead of variables:

```
declare @new_employment_startdate datetime = convert (datetime, '2017-01-01', 121);
declare @new_employment_enddate datetime  = convert (datetime, '2018-01-14', 121);

select 
        datediff(month, @new_employment_startdate, @new_employment_enddate) 
    +   case when   
                    datediff(month, dateadd(ms, -3, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, @new_employment_startdate), 0)), @new_employment_startdate) = 1
                and datediff(month,@new_employment_enddate , dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, @new_employment_enddate) + 1, 0))                  = 1
                then 1
                else 0
        end;
```

Some explanations:
I check or start date is first month day AND end date is last month day. At this case I add +1 to standard datediff by month.

You can better understand my used datetime manipulations by using these example queries: https://gist.github.com/runnerlt/60636b029ab47845fdfd8924ed482e61

Comment: Its date manipulations to get day start or day end. Or, at my case, to get next day first second. You can try these queries to clear it out:

https://gist.github.com/runnerlt/60636b029ab47845fdfd8924ed482e61

Comment: No, it isnt hardcode. By mssql documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx datetime accuracy is rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds.
Example of problematic case: select convert(datetime, '2017-01-12 23:59:59.999', 121);

Comment: Its more likely constant, working in all possible situations, and described in sql server documentation. Not hardcoded case. You can interpret adding month(1) as hardcode by using same logic. And cycle increment operation by 1 as hardcode too. P.S. most sql server developers knows about the documented datetime precision constants .000, .003, 007. No any magic here. Its documented.

Comment: Your clarity is based on hardcode, and because of this, its not working in >99% of possible cases. Anyway, our discussion was useful because of discussed methods how to manipulate data type datetime, and this potentialy helps others to better understand this (deprecated) data type.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add 1 more day in your End Date.
DATEDIFF(MONTH, NEW_EMPLOYMENT_STARTDATE, DATEADD(DD,1,NEW_EMPLOYMENT_ENDDATE))

You could match the output with MS Excel.